# How to display the details of a model item in delete view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I've been working on a Pizza application using Asp.Net Core Web Application. I've created a view to delete a user, but the user's information doesn't show up when I open the delete view. Any help would be appreciated.

I've double checked the data is being pulled from the database by creating a details view. This view works perfectly. The information is there and is being pulled from the database, I'm just not sure why it isn't appearing in the delete file

This is the view:

```
@model PizzaBoxWeb.Models.User

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Delete";
}

<h1>Delete</h1>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>User</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserId)
        </dd>
        <!--and all the rest of the data members-->
    </dl>

    <form asp-action="Delete">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" /> |
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is the delete function in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id, IFormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            db.DeleteUser(db.GetUser(id));
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I want the username and all of the user's information to appear before they're deleted, but currently the only thing being shown is the name of the information field.

Comment: Can you show the controller action that returns this view?

Comment: You should have something like `return View(model)` in the controller returning the `Delete` view